# Can I test a wstring::iterator for equality with a non-specific ::end?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm hoping to overload operator[]. I wish to accept a std::wstring::iterator as the argument to this method. However, I wish to increment this iterator until I reach the end of the wstring. Is there a way to do this? Here's some pseudo-ish-code which will hopefully make my proposition clear:

```
MyClass operator[](std::wstring::iterator it)
{
    /* Obviously this wstring::iterator::parent method is a figment
     * of my imagination; but hopefully it'll give the reader some
     * idea what I wish to achieve. */
    while (++it != it.parent_wstring.end())
        { party(); }
}
```

I had attempted to compare with a type-cast nullptr as follows:

```
if (it == (std::wstring::iterator)nullptr)
    { party(); }
```

and had this wondrous idea:

```
if (it == std::wstring(L"").end())
    { party(); }
```

but neither worked. Apologies (and some gleeful sadism) if either of the above efforts resulted in a cringe.

Comment: What is that good for?

Comment: I can only accept one argument to operator[]. And everyone knows parties with two arguments are terrible. Of course, I can just write a method with two arguments; but I'm trying to be really clever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Sorta.

```
if (*it == 0)
        { party(); }
```

This gets me the party I wanted. Please, any other answers (that are maybe a better idea than essentially dereferencing the end iterator) are encouraged! I'm going to go find out how much I can rely on that zero being there..

Comment: That is undefined behavior if it == end

Comment: Indeed it is. However, wstring inherits from basic_string. Which (if it's a c-string) will always have the zero. If the standard insists this will be the case; I will proceed with reckless abandon. Hopefully nobody else ever uses my software, right?

Comment: (Though I suspect an implementation detail like this might be omitted..)